# Take the lines between two specific values from different columns in a txt file

Tags: text-processing, awk, command-line, columns

I have a txt file (as show below) with many columns and I need to get the lines contained between the position of the second column to the position of the third column.

```
1       10385389        10385390        .       21
1       10385390        10385391        .       22
1       10385391        10385392        .       22
1       10385392        10385393        .       21
1       10385393        10385394        .       22
1       10385394        10385395        .       25
1       10385395        10385396        .       25
1       10385396        10385397        .       25
1       10385397        10385398        .       25
1       10385398        10385399        .       25
```

Taking this example imagine I want to select from 10385391 to 10385397  which desired output would be

```
1       10385391        10385392        .       22
1       10385392        10385393        .       21
1       10385393        10385394        .       22
1       10385394        10385395        .       25
1       10385395        10385396        .       25
1       10385396        10385397        .       25
```

Bonus: It is also important that if the start position is not found take instead the closes one. In the example provided that is not gonna happen because there is a correlative serie but in case I get a file like this

```
1       10385389        10385390        .       21
1       10385391        10385392        .       22
1       10385392        10385393        .       21
1       10385393        10385394        .       22
```

I would like to avoid error is the user introduces 10385390 and this is not found in the second column.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself, and tried anything yourself? If there is always a 1 in the first column, and if I am not interested in the bonus, `sed` is the right tool: `sed -n "/^1 *$start/,/^1 *$end/p"`. If the first column can't be predicted, `awk` may have to be used. The bonus makes the task much more difficult, and `awk` would be the right tool. What do you mean by "closest one" in your example, 10385389 or 10385391?

Comment: Are the numbers in column 2 and 3 always sorted in ascending order? Would it be correct to say you want to print all the lines where the second column's value is greater or equal to the starting point _and_ the third column's value is less or equal to the ending point? (Asking this because a positive answer would make a robust solution simpler).

Comment: (1) It's good to provide examples, but you need to ***explain*** the general situation better.  As a trivial example, I could solve the first part with `sed -n '3,8p'` (to print the third through eighth lines).  Obviously that's not what you want.  @berndbausch suggests `sed -n "/^1 *$start/,/^1 *$end/p"` which is wrong even for your example, but `sed -n "/$start/,/$end/p"` would be close — but it would fail if you had a 10385397 in the second column in the fourth through the seventh line — so, is that a possibility?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … (2) Also, is it possible that you might have a value like 99910385397999 or abc10385397xyz in the file? (3) Please don't use eight-digit numbers in your example unless you really *really **really*** need to. You need to show between ten and thirty different values; you could do that with two-digit numbers. But the most important thing is that a reader should be able to glance at any two numbers and see immediately whether they are the same. (4) Even assuming that "closes" is a typo for "closest", I don't understand the ‘‘bonus’’. *Explain* what you mean, and show the desired output.

Comment: Are the coordinates always on the positive strand and on chromosome 1?

Comment: You have a couple of answers containing scripts that will work (if I understand your question correctly) so I've upvoted them rather than posting my own similar answer but FWIW I'd write it as `awk -v beg=10385391 -v end=10385397 '(beg <= $2) && ($3 <= end)' file` so it's clear just from a glance at the code that you're trying to print lines where `$2->$3` is inside `beg->end`. Note that there's a potential error case if `$2` is greater than `$3` where `$2` could be greater than `end` and or `$3` less than `beg` but I assume you cant have that in your data.

Answer (score 5):

Start and stop conditions can be handled directly in AWK:

```
awk '$2 == "10385391",$3 == "10385397"'
```

This will output all lines starting with the line where the second field is “10385391”, and ending with the line where the third field is “10385397”.

To handle more flexible criteria, we can consider that you want any line where the first and second fields have values between 10385391 and 10385397:

```
awk '$2 >= 10385391 && $3 <= 10385397'
```

If the input contains multiple series of lines matching the criteria, they will all be output.

Answer (score 2):

command

```
 awk '$2 == "10385391" { f=1 } $3 == "10385397" { f=0; print }; f' filename
```

This looks for `10385391` in the 2nd column, and sets `f` to one when it's found.  This causes this line and all lines for which `f` has the value one to be printed (this is done via the trailing `f` in the `awk` code).  Whenever the 3rd column is `10385397`, `f` is reset to zero to avoid printing further lines, and the current line is printed.

output

```
1       10385391        10385392        .       22
1       10385392        10385393        .       21
1       10385393        10385394        .       22
1       10385394        10385395        .       25
1       10385395        10385396        .       25
1       10385396        10385397        .       25
```

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
awk -v begin=10385390 -v end=10385397 '($2 >= begin && $2 <= end) || ($3 >= begin && $3 <= end) || (begin <= $2 && end >= $3)' file
```

This returns any line with a `[$2,$3]` range overlapping the given `[begin,end]` range.

For the given data, this returns

```
1       10385389        10385390        .       21
1       10385390        10385391        .       22
1       10385391        10385392        .       22
1       10385392        10385393        .       21
1       10385393        10385394        .       22
1       10385394        10385395        .       25
1       10385395        10385396        .       25
1       10385396        10385397        .       25
1       10385397        10385398        .       25
```

To only get lines with a `[$2,$3]` range that is *inside* the given `[begin,end]` range:

```bsh
awk -v begin=10385390 -v end=10385397 '$2 >= begin && $3 <= end' file
```

Comment: Your first answer doesn't even produce the desired output shown in the question.  Your second version does, but so would ``sed -n '3,8p'``; i.e., it happens to give the right result, but it doesn't do the job that the question asks for.  You seem to be making unstated assumptions about the data. (The other two answers seem to do the right thing.)

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Good evening! My second variation gives the intended output, but it's really just the same as Stephen's answer. Therefore, I assumed that this is genomic data, in which case using "the closest" coordinate is nonsense, and what they actually want to do is to get the lines with ranges overlapping the given query range.